# replace start of url up to .com using reg expression in jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I am trying to see how to use reg expressions to replace  a url up to the .com, with something like local host. I am not a guru with expressions, so having a lot of troubles doing this. It is so we can have a Chrome extension for our localhost, and swap all urls to point to local host for debugging. So the expression needs to find anything like the following:

*.com/ --> and beyond stays the same, but up to the .com is swapped with our temp string value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `url = url.replace(/^.+?\.com\b/i, 'http://localhost');`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use chrome extension then * is valid

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
            function(details) {
              details.url = "http://localhost";
            },
            {urls: ["*://*.*.com/*"]}, //could also be urls: ["*://my.host.com/*"]
//also if you want to change all urls you can use ["<all_urls>"]
            ["blocking"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish it with this if you want to go the regex route:

```
.*?(?=\.com\b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aA5rT3/1

It uses a positive lookahead to match up until the `.com`.

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/520zdnsL/